# vim autoindent not proper when a { inside comments

Tags: c++, vim, comments, auto-indent

I found vim is not indenting correctly/reformatting my cpp file correctly when a '{' is present inside a comment. Like the

```
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    if(1){
        if(1){
            //if(){ 
            cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
        }
    } 
        // if you insert a line from here, it will be indented here
} 

int haha(){

}
```

and when I gg=G, I got

```
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    if(1){
        if(1){
            //if(){
            cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
            double a=1.5;
            cerr<<"   "<<fabs(a)<<endl;
        }
        }
        // if you insert a line from here, it will be indented here
    }

    int haha(){

    }
```

If I remove the 
    /if(){
line, it will just be fine.

I'm using the following .vimrc

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" start of my plugins
Plugin 'scrooloose/NERDCommenter'
Plugin 'Tabular'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/matchit.zip'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/restore_view.vim'
"Plugin 'WolfgangMehner/vim-plugins'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to au
to-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line


set wildmenu
set showcmd

" Use case insensitive search, except when using capital letters
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set laststatus=2
set vb
"set nostartofline

set autoindent
set showmatch
set incsearch
syntax enable
syntax on
set hlsearch
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized

" foldings 
"set foldmethod=syntax
"set foldlevel=1
"set foldnestmax=1
"autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
"autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview 
"set foldignore=

set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
let mapleader = ","
```

Thank you!

Comment: Mine has the same odd behavior as yours, with the comment.  First time I noticed it.   I only have smartindent+autoindent to mess with the indentation.

Comment: Maybe a case of *It's not a bug, it's a feature*.

Comment: The commented out `if(){` seems to be causing the issue. Specifically the `{`. I assume this is a bug w/ Vim. If this is indeed a bug, you should submit it to Vim's [issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues)

Comment: Tend to believe that vim is working fine. It is just that you are having an extra `}` which is causing the issue

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Thanks. Perhaps it's a feature but no one writing a plugin to fix it is strange. They already wrote matchit for fixing the `%` jump sign for the same issue.

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks. I reported the issue.